# Bulk edit contents of pages

Tags: editor, content, bulk

I would like to know how to edit the content area for many pages.  I have many options for bulk editing of pages, such as *parent* and *sidebar*, like this image:

[image: bulk edit options]

But I can't do this for the actual content of each page.  I have a large number of pages that will have the same content, and it would be great to be able to check their boxes on "pages", and quick edit all them for this.

Comment: Can you give some more details on why you have pages with the same content? This doesn't really sound reasonable and will probably cause issues with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_content

Comment: Thanks for asking - the content will be tweaked later for each individual page.  If I can get the same content on all of these pages initially, it will be much faster than opening each one and pasting.

Comment: @kraftner Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any other readers I'd like to add in advance that this only really makes sense if you are kind of creating drafts or templates or whatever you want to call it that will be changed later on. Otherwise you'll at least deal with [SEO penalties due to duplicate content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_content).

Unfortunately this functionality isn't part of WordPress by default so you'd need to find or create a plugin for that.

One other option is to use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) in case you do feel comfortable using the command line.

```
wp post update <ids> --post_content=<new content>
```

Using the [wp post update](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/update/) command you can easily edit the content of multiple posts. So for example if you want to edit the posts with the ids 1, 2 and 5 to be changed to "other content" use this command:

```
wp post update 1 2 5 --post_content="other content"
```

You can see the ID from the edit screen by hovering the edit link and looking for the ID there.

> site.tld/wp-admin/post.php?post=**5**&action=edit

To easily get all ids for some condition like a category (books in this example) just use the [`wp post list`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/list/) command.

```
wp post list --category_name=books --format=ids
```

This will return something like `1 2 5` which you can then use in the query mentioned above.

Be sure to read the documentation of the commands mentioned above because they offer various other options and commands that could help, like getting the content from a file.

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to trying this out.  I'll have to get into the wp-cli first.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly.  I had my server teammate help me get set up correctly with the cli first, and your solution was ideal. :)